# Kafka не видит Zookeeper в docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-kafka, zookeeper

Хочу развернуть `Kafka` в докере, но она не запускается, не может найти `zookeeper`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "test"
      POSTGRES_USER: "root"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "secret"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - kafka-net
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - kafka-net
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "wallet:10:1"
    networks:
      - kafka-net
networks:
  kafka-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Смотрю полчаса на конфиг и не вижу ошибку. При запуске выдается такое исключение:

```
[2024-02-07 06:26:25,373] ERROR Unable to resolve address: zookeeper:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider)
kafka       | java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper
```

Не может резолвить адрес `zookeper`. Но ведь имя сервиса `zookeeper` преобразуется в `DNS` запись для контейнера, по которой можно найти этот контейнер в сети. Разве не так? Как исправить проблему?

Comment: Не факт что дело в этом, но я бы добавл     `depends_on: zookeeper` для сервиса кафки. Может порядо запуска решит проблему.

Comment: @Alpensin не помогло, и кафка к тому же продолжает переподключаться в цикле к этому адресу, а он не разрешается

Comment: Конфиг верный. Иногда почему-то неправильно работает резолвер. Посмотрите что с ним: `docker-compose exec kafka cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Должен быть `nameserver 127.0.0.11` на Linux.

Comment: PS. Скопировал ваш конфиг, запустил. Работает - по крайней мере нет ошибок в логах. Иногда бывают причуды docker. Иногда нужно перезапустить демона `sudo systemctl restart docker`